# Function maximisation using non-linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, optimization, nonlinear-regression, reinforcement-learning

I'm working on a function maximisation problem, witch is related to a non-linear regression problem.

The problem is as follows:

The target variable is $y$ and is continuous. The data set consists of some features $x_1,\dots,x_N$, $y$ and a parameter $p$, which is a continuous and bounded. The parameter $p$ is a feature that I can tune for new samples.

The **objective** is to, given a new data point (i.e., a set of fetaures $x_1, \dots, x_N$), **find the parameter $p$** that will yield **maximum** $y$.

This is problem is somehow similar to some reinforcement learning problems. New data points are being sampled at constant time intervals, for each new data point ($x_1, \dots, x_N$) I get to decide a parameter $p$ and then I get a feedback $y$. For each new data point, I want to decide the best $p$ so that $y$ is maximized.

My approach to solve this problem is as follows:

1. Use non-linear regression techniques to estimate $y$ as a function of $p$ and $x_1, \dots, x_N$ (i.e, regression-$y$).
2. Evaluate regression-$y$ over all possible (well just a subset using global optimization techinques) values of $p$ in order to find the one that yields higher $y$.
3. Construct a second data set with $x_1, \dots, x_N$ and $p^*$, where $p^*$ is the parameter that yielded higher $y$ in regression-$y$.
4. Use another non-linear regression to estimate $p^*$ as a function of $x_1, \dots, x_N$ (i.e., regression-$p$).
5. Use the regression-$p$ to estimate the best $p$ for each new data point.

I'm wondering if I could use another procedure that estimates the best $p^*$.

Comment: How are you going to construct a second data set?  Is not your data fixed?

Comment: @generic_user the values of $x_1$ through $x_N$ are fixed, but $p$ is an adjustable parameter. I haven't thought hard about this, but it seems to be a situation in which $p$ would always end up at one of its bounds.

Comment: Adjusting $p$ to maximize $y$ is trivial.  Instead, do you want to choose a combination of $x$'s to maximize $y$ given $p$?  That'd be a more typical problem, given an estimate of $p$ that minimizes some loss function.

Comment: @generic_user Adjusting $p$ to maximize $y$ is exactly what I want. For each set of features x's I can decide the value of $p$ and then I observe an $y$. $y$ is what I want to maximize.

Comment: @EdM you are right. $p$ ends up in one of its bounds if the regession-$y$ is linear in $p$. Thats why I don't use linear regression for this problem.

Comment: If you are using $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + ...+ \beta_N x_N + \beta_{N+1} p + \varepsilon$, then $p=\infty$ gives you the maximal possible $y=\infty$... If you want to opitmize a function, why not directly use optimization algorithm that optimizes your desired objective?

Comment: I think you will need to provide more details about what you are trying to accomplish. The original question didn't make it clear that you were using nonlinear regression, and in that case the details of the nonlinear regression approach might be crucial. Also, how are you handling the coefficient(s) for $p$? It seems that even with bounds on the value of $p$ you could make $y$ as large as you want with a large-magnitude coefficient for $p$, even in non-linear regression. It would be best to edit the question rather than to elaborate in a comment.

Comment: @EdM question edited. Let me know if there are other parts that need more detail.